# Problem with login page

Tags: 7

On my drupal website every page with "/nl" in the url, give an error.
Only the home page works, because there is no "/nl" in the url.

Example:
Home page: http://wnl.be/
All other menus, links, ... on the website give errors, such as http://www.wnl.be/nl/wagenpark

The big problem is that the login page also "/nl" contained in the url. You can test it: www.wnl.be?q=user/login

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have infinite redirection which causes the page not to load. (stops after x redirects)

It happens on every page (the once that load and the once that don't load) see my screenshot of the network tab to see it in action:

[image]

Comment: Have you an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What custom modules are you using? Have you added aliases that create an infinite loop? Have you changed the .htaccess file? I will need more information to help you I'm afraid.